# Best way to use HttpClient to post a file in terms of effeciency

Tags: java, httpclient, load-testing

I have to build a fairly custom load testing tool, and because of this I don't want to use JMeter (lets assume for a moment that the level of customization cannot be done using jmeter).

One import part of this load testing tool is sending a XML for to a API endpoing.

How can I improve the below code to make this fast/efficient?

```
private boolean PostErrorToApi() throws IOException {
       File xmlSample = new File("/path/to/file/sample.xml");

       CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

       HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8090/some/api/method/get/");
       httpPost.setEntity(new FileEntity(xmlSample, "text/xml, application/xml"));

       CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

       String line = "";

       try {
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

           while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println(line);
           }
       } finally {
           response.close();
       }

       if (line.equals("200 OK"))
           return true;
       else
           return false;
   }
```

My goal is to get to a few thousand requests per second (http latency shouldn't be that much of an issue since this will be in a private network).

I'm not trying to get a real world scenerio here, the goal is to see if the services can stay up for 48 hours and just to monitor any issues that might come up etc.

Comment: Also, I get a deprecated warning for FileEntity, what is the new way?

Comment: Do you have any errors or unexpected behavior?

Comment: No it works fine in my local testing, meaning it posts the file fine and I get a response and no exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly it's IO bound task, not CPU. 
You can try to cache file in memory, without reading it every time from disc. Cache instance of httpClient, use same connection to send file multiple time. Spawn multiple threads in one JVM, each thread will create separate connection. If it's not enough, create multiple processes, run it on different machines and collect results

Also `readLine` will block until data will be available, so you task will be stuck and you will never know if you have any problems. Set SO_TIMEOUT for reading response.

Comment: How do I set the timeout, I'm creating the client using .createDefault(); currently...

Comment: I saw that, but that is using the older api not the `CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();` builder style.